# How to reflect dates on specific cells corresponding to a list item chosen in Excel?

Tags: excel, vba

Basically I have an excel sheet used for tracking statuses in hiring, where there are around 5 statuses (Briefing, Advertising, Shortlisting, Selection, Offering) and against each vacancy there's a status cell as a list of the above statuses and it's changed manually based on the status of the vacancy.

I have found a vba code (attached below) to reflect in a certain cell the date that the status has been changed, and if I choose another status (basically update the status) it overwrites the previous input, but what I need to do is a bit more complicated.

I created a column for each status and I need this code to reflect the date on each status's cell corresponding to the one I have chosen from the list, for example, choosing briefing for a specific vacancy will reflect the date on the corresponding cell in the "briefing" column, and if I change the status for that specific vacancy from the list to "selection", a date will reflect on the corresponding cell in the "selection" column.

The code that I've found so far is below:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
'Update 20140722
Dim WorkRng As Range
Dim Rng As Range
Dim xOffsetColumn As Integer
Set WorkRng = Intersect(Application.ActiveSheet.Range("N:N"), Target)
xOffsetColumn = 1
If Not WorkRng Is Nothing Then
Application.EnableEvents = False
For Each Rng In WorkRng
If Not VBA.IsEmpty(Rng.Value) Then
Rng.Offset(0, xOffsetColumn).Value = Now
Rng.Offset(0, xOffsetColumn).NumberFormat = "dd-mm-yyyy"
Else
Rng.Offset(0, xOffsetColumn).ClearContents
End If
Next
Application.EnableEvents = True
End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You can modify your code and add [Select Case Statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/VBA/language-reference-vba/articles/select-case-statement?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev11.query%3FappId%3DDev11IDEF1%26l%3Dpl-PL%26k%3Dk(vblr6.chm1008810)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-Office.Version%3Dv15)%26rd%3Dtrue) to adjust column offset depending on data entry:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

  Dim WorkRng As Range
  Dim Rng As Range
  Dim xOffsetColumn As Long

  Set WorkRng = Intersect(Application.ActiveSheet.Range("N:N"), Target)
  If Not WorkRng Is Nothing Then
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    For Each Rng In WorkRng
      Select Case Rng.Value2
        Case "Briefing"
          xOffsetColumn = 1  'Column O
        Case "Advertising"
          xOffsetColumn = 2  'Column P
        Case "Shortlisting"
          xOffsetColumn = 3  'Column Q
        Case "Selection"
          xOffsetColumn = 4  'Column R
        Case "Offering"
          xOffsetColumn = 5  'Column S
        Case Else
          xOffsetColumn = 6  'Column T - entry not listed above
      End Select
      Rng.Offset(0, xOffsetColumn).Value = Now
      Rng.Offset(0, xOffsetColumn).NumberFormat = "dd-mm-yyyy"
    Next
    Application.EnableEvents = True
  End If
End Sub
```